# Proof by strong induction question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

To do a proof by strong induction, we follow 3 steps:

**Statement**: Begin with a precise statement of the formula to be proven.

**The Basis Case**: State the number $k$ where you're starting your induction, and the formula $f(k)$ to be proven, and then prove it.

**The Induction Case**: State the inductive hypothesis $f(n)$, and the formula $f(n+1)$ to be proven. Prove the result, clearly indicating when the inductive hypothesis is used.

We have to give a proof for the following theorem:

2) Formalize the theorem: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k = \frac{1}{k+1}\cdot n^{k+1}$$
by proving by induction $\nabla n^{(k)}=kn^{(k−1)}$ for all natural numbers $k\geq 1$. It may help to first prove the product rule for differentiation: 
$$\nabla f(n)\cdot g(n)=f(n)\nabla g(n)+g(n−1)\nabla f(n) .$$

Comment: Note that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i = a_{n+1}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$... i.e. you can "*break off a piece*" of the sum to be computed separately.

Comment: While $\Delta n^{(k)} = kn^{(k-1)}$, $\nabla n^{(k)} = k(n-1)^{(k-1)}$...

Comment: Also, the "theorem to be formalized" is, I suspect, $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^{(k)} = n^{(k+1)}/(k+1)$.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in a few numbers?  You may notice that $n^{k+1}/(k+1)$ is often not an integer, while the left-hand side always is.  (And so is $n^{(k+1)}/(k+1)$.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the statement is wrong, no one has been interested enough to post an answer, and OP hasn't been interested enough to engage with the comments.